# Application can't run in Samsung S6

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android App compiled and packaged. It works on any device Blu Dash 3.5, Samsung S5 and inferior, Hummer, etc.

In Xamarin Studio I go to *Options* --> *Application Build* --> *Advanced* --> *Supported ABIs* and mark all of them:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- x86
- arm64-v8a
- x86_64

So, I put the .apk package on the Samsung S6 and install with no problem. But when I run the app, stop working (the application exit without any message).

**LOGCAT**: 06-17 17:53:33.797: E/mono-rt(21778): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL

Is anyone have the same problem? What do you suggest in order to fix the situation?

Comment: Define "stop working".  Does it give an error?  If so, what is it? Crash to desktop?

Comment: The application exit without any message. Just close.

Comment: Why not try to debbugin in your device?

Comment: No error while debugging.

Comment: What does Logcat say is happening?

Comment: Connect your phone to your Mac/PC.  From Xamarin Studio, click on "Tools->Android Device Monitor".  When that opens up, select your device from the list.  Start the application, and look at the LogCat window.  This will show you the app logs, and if an exception occurs, it will tell you what it is.  Copy and paste that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution (temporally). You must deselect **arm64-v8a** from Options --> Application Build --> Advanced --> Supported ABIs.

That solves the problem.